# C++ Function wont call into main properly

Tags: c++, function

Now i'm sure the answer to this is quite simple.  Im quite new to coding and cant seem to call a function properly  into the main function.  Here's what im trying to accomplish: the function is supposed to compare a user input to another function that randomly generates a number and the point is to keep the randomization and the user input in two different function.  Here's the code.  Thanks folks!

```
#include <random>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::random_device seed;
std::mt19937 mersenneTwister(seed());

int RandomInt(int min, int max);
int GuessNum(int NumGuessed);

int main() 
{
    int MagicNumber = RandomInt(1, 100);
    int GuessNum(int MagicNumber);







}
int RandomInt(int min, int max)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(mersenneTwister);
}
int GuessNum(int NumGuessed)
// supposed to ask for user input in main?
{
    int guess = 0;
    cout << "Guess what number did the computer generate\n";
    cin >> guess;

    if (guess == NumGuessed)
    {
        cout << "You win\n";

    }

    else if (guess > NumGuessed)
    {
        cout << "Higher\n";

    }

    else if (guess > NumGuessed)
    {
        cout << "Lower\n";

    }

    else if (guess < 1 || guess > 100) {

        cout << "invalid input\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int GuessNum(int MagicNumber);` this is declaration. This `GuessNum( MagicNumber);` is invocation.

Comment: Oh, this worked as well, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int MagicNumber = RandomInt(1, 100);
```

Invokes RandomInt while

```
int GuessNum(int MagicNumber);
```

Declares a function in main function. You need to invoke it with:

```
int res = GuessNum(MagicNumber);
```

Comment: Ok, just to make sure I understand, I need to create a variable, then store Guessnum's value, which is also the Magic Number's value?

Comment: @Yuty06 your function GuessNum returns an int. You can store its returned value in a variable or not. So just GuessNum(MagicNumber); is valid too.

Answer (score 0):

1. To call function `GuessNum()` in `main()` you need to write `GuessNum(MagicNumber);`
   . That `int GuessNum(int MagicNumber);` is a declaration.
2. You need to include `<iostream>` in order to use `std::cout`.
3. You have made a careless mistake: you wrote `else if (guess > NumGuessed)` for twice.
4. You have a logic problem in branching. After `guess` is tested for `==` `<` or `>` with `NumGuessed`, you have exhausted all possibilities and it's meaningless then to test `if (guess < 1 || guess > 100)`. Rearrange your branches.